# MATLAB context menu for a list box not showing (in GUIDE)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I'm creating a matlab GUI using GUIDE. I can't get the context menus to show. This might have to do with a bug in the visible property of the context menus (which is always 'off')

here's an old thread describing same problem without much a solution: 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/253898

Any workarounds or a fix would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

workaround: 
request the context menu handle on the list box's callback:

```
function lstGates_Callback(hObject, ~, ~)

    % -ignore- matlab right click menu not showing bug workaround
    ctm = get(hObject, 'UIContextMenu'); 

    ...
    ...
end
```